# "Хлебные законы" — нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Нигде не могу найти указаний по поводу "хлебных законов". Нужны ли кавычки или нет? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**Хлебные законы** — совокупность законов, регулирующих государственную политику в отношении хлеба. **Возможны обе формы записи**: "хлебные законы",  хлебные законы/хлебный закон.

Кавычки обозначают **условность** названия. Часто в одной статье сначала используется название в кавычках, а затем кавычки опускаются, когда читателю уже понятно, о чем идет речь.

**Примечание**

Надо сказать, что написание подобных сочетаний подчиняются **общим правилам**. Существует **4 формы письма:** имена собственные (прописная буква, в кавычках и без кавычек) и   нарицательные названия (строчная буква, в кавычках и без кавычек).

Иногда одно и тоже название в специальной  литературе или официальных текстах пишется как имя собственное, а в обычных изданиях может считаться нарицательным именем. Малоизвестные **условные** названия  сначала пишутся  в кавычках, но потом кавычки могут стать необязательными.

**Для справок:**

Leges frumentariae (с лат. — «хлебные законы») — условное название совокупности древнеримских законов, регулировавших государственную политику обеспечения населения хлебом — как с помощью его продажи римским гражданам по сниженным ценам, так и путём бесплатных раздач.

«Хлебные законы» (англ. Corn Laws) — законы о пошлине на ввозимое зерно, действовавшие в Великобритании в период между 1815 и 1846 годами. Являлись торговым барьером, который защищал английских фермеров и землевладельцев от конкуренции с дешёвым иностранным зерном.